# Objective-C pass by reference vs pass by pointer. What's the difference? And why do we need it at all?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parameter-passing

In Objective-C I saw two common patterns for passing objects to functions. Basically all objects to functions are passed by reference like this:
`-(void) someFunc:(UIImage*)image;` this is pass by reference, isn't it?

But then what is this:
`-(void) someFunc2:(UIImage**)image`?? Is it also passing by reference? Or passing by pointer to pointer? Or what? I don't understand what is an actual difference (but I saw this code a lot). And the main question: why do we need this pointer to pointer passing : `-(void) someFunc2:(UIImage**)image`? Thanks.

Comment: All object parameters are pass by reference because they're pointers.

Comment: @Aaron Actually, the object pointer parameters are always passed by value.

Comment: OK. So then what is the difference between value/reference in this case? Either way, the object pointer points to the object being passed and can thus be changed by the function receiving it. Is that inaccurate?

Comment: rmaddy means that the POINTER itself is passed by value. True "pass by reference" doesn't exist in objective-c

Comment: in practice, passing a pointer to an object by value, and passing an object by reference a la C# are functionally equivalent.

Comment: That's what I was getting at with my comment.

Comment: @Lance: You cannot "pass an object" in C#. There are no "object types" in C#.

Comment: @newacct could you explain more what you mean? I thought everything in C# was an object.

Comment: @Lance: C# consists of value types and reference types. Value types include structs, primitives, and enums. The others are reference types, whose values are references, i.e. pointers to objects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Passing a double pointer allows the function to swap out the object you pass in. A good example is all of the many Cocoa APIs that pass a double pointer to an NSError. Take a look at this:

```
NSError *error = nil;
Result *result = [self someMethodWithPossibleError:&error];
if (![result isValid]) {
    //handle the error
    NSLog(@"Error occurred: %@", error);
}
```

In this case, we aren't passing an actual error instance, however since we are passing a pointer to our error, this allows them to create an NSError instance in this method, and after exiting, we will be pointing at that new instance.

Comment: Bad example, though.  You should *never* test the `error` to see if the method passed or failed.  You must *always* test the result of the method and then consider the `error` only if the return value of the method indicated an error.  (Obviously, `someMethodWithPossibleError:` could be implemented using a different pattern, but that would be explicitly against the patterns used across the system).

Comment: @bbum good point! Edited my answer.